# Javascript Loop - Adding a var to the while condition?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

Basically I want to count and display the amount of months it would take to get to a certain point (savings balance) based on a contribution every month.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function howLong(initial,interest,goal,added){
    var initialDeposit = parseInt(initial);
    var interestInt = parseInt(interest);
    var targetSaving = parseInt(goal);
    var contribution = parseInt(added);
    var monthCount = 0;
    while(initialDeposit <= targetSaving){
        monthCount++;
        initialDeposit+contribution
    }
    alert(monthCount)
}
```

Here is my html form:

```
<form>
Initial Deposit:<br />
<input type="number" id="initial"><br /><br />
Interest:<br />
<input type="number" id="interest"><br /><br />
Target savings amount:<br />
<input type="number" id="goal"><br /><br />
Monthly Contribution:<br />
<input type="number" id="contribution"><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="How Long!?" onclick="howLong(document.getElementById('initial').value,document.getElementById('interest').value,document.getElementById('goal').value),document.getElementById('contribution').value">
</form>
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: `initialDeposit += contribution` or `initialDeposit = initialDeposit + contribution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the value of `contribution` to `initialDeposit`.

```
initialDeposit += contribution;
```

For the other problem, you have an error in the call of the function

```
document.getElementById('goal').value),document.getElementById('contribution').value"
                                     ^ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> should go >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ^
```

shold be

```
onclick="howLong(
    document.getElementById('initial').value,
    document.getElementById('interest').value,
    document.getElementById('goal').value,
    document.getElementById('contribution').value
)"
```

The last round bracket is closing to early.

```js
function howLong(initial, interest, goal, added) {
  var initialDeposit = parseInt(initial);
  var interestInt = parseInt(interest);
  var targetSaving = parseInt(goal);
  var contribution = parseInt(added);
  var monthCount = 0;
  while (initialDeposit <= targetSaving) {
    monthCount++;
    initialDeposit += contribution;
  }
  alert(monthCount)
}
```

```html
<form>
  Initial Deposit:<br />
  <input type="number" id="initial"><br /><br /> Interest:
  <br />
  <input type="number" id="interest"><br /><br /> Target savings amount:<br />
  <input type="number" id="goal"><br /><br /> Monthly Contribution:<br />
  <input type="number" id="contribution"><br /><br />
  <input type="button" value="How Long!?" onclick="howLong(document.getElementById('initial').value,document.getElementById('interest').value,document.getElementById('goal').value,document.getElementById('contribution').value)">
</form>
```

Comment: It must be a problem in my form, this just gives me monthCount = 1 and shows it in an alert (using values initialDeposit = 1000, targetSaving = 1500, contribution = 50).

Comment: @Kyle: it says `11` here: http://jsfiddle.net/jgf0xh7o/. If you get rid of the loop ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tdw5xv4a/), you will get 10, which is actually the correct answer (you should have `<` in your condition, not `<=`).

Comment: @Groo Oh i see, so it's definitely my form then I guess?

Comment: right. it is the function, which have the closing bracket to early and omit the `added` parameter.

Comment: @Kyle: just note that `<=` is wrong, and you don't need a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `initialDeposit += contribution;`

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `+=` operator and interest as well.

```js
function howLong(){
    var initialDeposit = parseInt(document.getElementById('initial').value);
    var interestInt = parseInt(document.getElementById('interest').value);
    var targetSaving = parseInt(document.getElementById('goal').value);
    var contribution = parseInt(document.getElementById('contribution').value);
    var monthCount = 0;
    while(initialDeposit <= targetSaving){
        monthCount++;
        initialDeposit += contribution + interestInt; //+= was missing and interestInt as well
    }
    alert(monthCount);
}
```

```html
<form>
Initial Deposit:<br />
<input type="number" id="initial"><br /><br />
Interest:<br />
<input type="number" id="interest"><br /><br />
Target savings amount:<br />
<input type="number" id="goal"><br /><br />
Monthly Contribution:<br />
<input type="number" id="contribution"><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="How Long!?" onclick="howLong()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out `initialDeposit += contribution` will solve the issue, but you don't need a loop here at all:

```
var monthCount = Math.ceil((targetSaving - initialDeposit)/contribution);
```

This is presuming that the contribution is constant, of course.